# React MUI V5 createTheme not render theme in shadow-root mount point

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

When I attach the shadow root with the MUI `createTheme` function, it is not rendering properly. I followed [this guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/shadow-dom/) on the MUI website but it didn't resolve my issue.

```
// App.js
const cache = createCache({
  key: 'css',
  prepend: true,
  container: shadowRoot,
  speedy: false
})

return (
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themes(customization)}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <NavigationScroll>
          <Routes />
        </NavigationScroll>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  </StyledEngineProvider>
);
```

```
// themes.js
const themeOptions = {
  direction: 'ltr',
  palette: themePalette(themeOption),
  mixins: {
    toolbar: {
      minHeight: '48px',
      padding: '16px',
      '@media (min-width: 600px)': {
        minHeight: '48px'
      }
    }
  },
  typography: themeTypography(themeOption)
};

const themes = createTheme(themeOptions);
themes.components = componentStyleOverrides(themeOption);

return themes;
```

```
// componentStyleOverrides
const shadowRoot = flowise.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('#mountPoint')[0];

MuiCssBaseline: {
  defaultProps: {
    container: shadowRoot
  },
  styleOverrides: {
    body: {
      scrollbarWidth: 'thin',
      scrollbarColor: theme?.customization?.isDarkMode
        ? `${theme.colors?.grey500} ${theme.colors?.darkPrimaryMain}`
           .
           .
           .
```

I try to mount it in shadow root, but it dosen't work:

[image: Failure to mount]

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're facing may be related to how you are attempting to attach the Material-UI styles to a component inside a Shadow DOM. To use Material-UI with Shadow DOM, you need to ensure that the styles are properly encapsulated within the Shadow DOM, and this may require some adjustments.

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to use Material-UI with Shadow DOM:

Import the necessary libraries:
import { createTheme, CssBaseline, StyledEngineProvider, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';

Create the cache and attach it to the Shadow DOM:

```
const shadowRoot = document.querySelector('#your-shadow-root-selector');                 
// Replace with your actual selector
const cache = createCache({
  key: 'css',
  prepend: true,
  container: shadowRoot,
  speedy: false,
});
```

Create your theme and include the cache:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  // Your theme configuration here
});
theme.components = componentStyleOverrides(theme);

return (
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        {/* Your app content */}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  </StyledEngineProvider>
);
```

Ensure that your componentStyleOverrides function sets the appropriate container property for MuiCssBaseline. Here's an example:

```
const componentStyleOverrides = (themeOption) => {
  const shadowRoot = document.querySelector('#your-shadow-root-selector'); // Replace with your actual selector

  return {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      defaultProps: {
        container: shadowRoot,
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        // Your styles here
      },
    },
    // Other component overrides
  };
};
```

Make sure you replace #your-shadow-root-selector with the actual selector for your Shadow DOM. The container property should point to your Shadow DOM's root element.

With these changes, Material-UI styles should be properly encapsulated within the Shadow DOM of your component. Make sure you are using the correct selectors and IDs for your specific use case.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9svX3.png <-- from this picture selector that you mean is <flowise-menu> right ? Shadow root that i use in containner  is get from document.querySelectorAll('flowise-menu')[0].shadowRoot but it not work.